# How to target labels with specific values and change their background color in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to set up data triggers to change the background color of specific labels when they contain "Failed". I have done similar things with datagrids but for some reason I can't get the triggers to work and show any changes. When I use the resource dictionary below it changes all labels in the window to the trigger color instead of just the label that contains "Failed". It might be worth noting that the datagrids I worked with before were in user controls and not plain windows. How can I just get the labels with "Failed" to have a different background color and not all labels on the page?

EDIT: I solved this using Tretoms solutions by using a converter and using textblocks instead of labels and binding my text and converter by doing the following. `Text="{Binding Path=SecurityAuditOverallResult}" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ContentToColorConverter}}" Foreground="Black"/> <Label`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SecurityAuditOverallResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink" ></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ComputerNameAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OSUpdatesAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FirewallAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileAndPrinterSharingAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AntivirusAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink" ></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InternetInformationServiceAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AutomaticLoginAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WorkstationAutolockAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PersonalInfoScanningAppAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UnauthorizedAppsAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PeerToPeerAppsAuditResult}"  Value="Failed">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is the window I am using the resource dictionary in.

```
<Window 
    x:Class="Domain_Audit_V2.ComputerInfoWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Domain_Audit_V2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{Binding Path=ComputerName}" 
    Style="{StaticResource RedWindowStyle}"
    MinHeight="300" MinWidth="350"
    MaxHeight="1020" MaxWidth="850">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/ComputerInfoDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="800" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Name:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=ComputerName}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Tag:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=ComputerTag}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Last Startup:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=LastStartUp}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Motherboard:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=MotherboardName}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="CPU:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=CpuName}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Os Architecture:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=OsArchitecture}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="RAM Size:" />
            <Label 
            Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="{Binding Path=RamSize}" />
            <Label
            Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Harddrive:" />
            <ProgressBar 
            Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Value="{Binding Path=HarddriveFreespace}"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="{Binding Path=HarddriveSize}"
            Width="450"/>

            <Label
        Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Status:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=SecurityAuditOverallResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Last Audit:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=LastAudit}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Computer Name Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=ComputerNameAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Computer Name Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=ComputerNameAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="OS Updates Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=OSUpdatesAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="OS Updates Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=OSUpdatesAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Firewall Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="14" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=FirewallAuditResult}" 
              />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Firewall Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=FirewallAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="FileAndPrinterSharing Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="16" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=FileAndPrinterSharingAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="17" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="FileAndPrinterSharing Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="17" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=FileAndPrinterSharingAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Antivirus Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="18" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=AntivirusAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Antivirus Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="19" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=AntivirusAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="InternetInformationServiceAuditResult:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=InternetInformationServiceAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="21" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Internet Information Service Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="21" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=InternetInformationServiceAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Automatic Login Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="22" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=AutomaticLoginAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="23" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Automatic Login Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="23" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=AutomaticLoginAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="24" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Workstation Autolock Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="24" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=WorkstationAutolockAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="25" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Workstation Autolock Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="25" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=WorkstationAutolockAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="26" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Personal Info Scanning App Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="26" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=PersonalInfoScanningAppAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="27" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Personal Info Scanning App Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="27" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=PersonalInfoScanningAppAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="28" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Unauthorized Apps Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="28" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=UnauthorizedAppsAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="29" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="Unauthorized Apps Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="29" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=UnauthorizedAppsAuditDetails}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="30" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="PeerToPeer Apps Audit Result:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="30" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=PeerToPeerAppsAuditResult}" />
            <Label
        Grid.Row="31" Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="PeerToPeer Apps Audit Details:" />
            <Label 
        Grid.Row="31" Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Content="{Binding Path=PeerToPeerAppsAuditDetails}" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

This is what it looks like when it is ran.
Only the Status and the column next to fileandprintersharing audit result should be highlighted because they contain "Failed".
[image: Window View]

Comment: You could bind the Label's Background to its own Content with a Binding Converter that checks if the Content string contains the word "Failed". You might also want to use TextBlocks instead of Labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with DataTrigger, but with IValueConverter - if it's OK for you:
Quick & Dirty:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LabelBack.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LabelBack"
    ...>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ContentToColorConverter x:Key="ContentToColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Failed" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ContentToColorConverter}}"/>
    <Label Content="Succeeded"  Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ContentToColorConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ContentToColorConverter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace LabelBack
{
    public class ContentToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == "Failed") return Brushes.LightCoral;
            return Brushes.LightGreen;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

EDIT:

I think all you need to do is, to change the xaml of this pop-up window with all the labels. There you have row content like:

```
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Name:" />
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Path=ComputerName}" />
```

Change it to:

```
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Name:" />
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Path=ComputerName}" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ContentToColorConverter}}"/>
```

And of course, you must have the reference to the converter class in the Window.Resources section of the same xaml

Comment: Where exactly would I want to make this class in? I'm still learning the project organization part of WPF MVVM, and to me it seems like this would be part of the xaml.cs for this window. However, it doesn't look like i'd want to do that because of the IValueConverter inheritance i'd need. Is this what you would call a helper class?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. This converter thing doesn't have much to do with MVVM. Or better said, it belongs to the "V" part of it, because it's all about the view. In my opinion the project structure is more flexible than that, to have a one for all definition of it. The XYConverter class can be anywhere in your project. I mostly put them into a Converters, or Helpers folder.  But there's no inheritance here. IValueConverter is an interface.

Comment: I've been trying to get the converter code to work, but for some reason I'm getting a NullReferenceException when I trigger the window and the Converter's Covert function tries the check if the value is "failed". For context this window is triggered when I click on a row in a datagrid that contains a specific computer, then this window with all the labels pops up and shows a detailed view of the computer.

Comment: I think my problem might be the reference to the class in the resources.  `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Domain_Audit_V2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{Binding Path=ComputerName}" 
    Style="{StaticResource RedWindowStyle}"
    MinHeight="300" MinWidth="350"
    MaxHeight="1020" MaxWidth="850">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ContentToColorConverter x:Key="ContentToColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>` I keep cross checking and can't find a difference between yours. My visual studio shows 0 references on my Convert method inside of the class though.

Comment: if there is something wrong with the namespace reference in the xaml (it's not found) then it's marked with blue squiggle lines. If the line is not marked you should be good to go. And if you are using visual studio (e.g. 2022 community) and type "xmlns:something="clr-namespace:" it should show you the possible namespaces. And as you continue, you should come to the required classname. But the fact that the reference count is 0 means nothing. VS does not check the xaml references.
Put a breakpoint into the converter class to see if it's hit.

Comment: I pushed a small project to github. I hope it helps: https://github.com/tretom2121/LabelBack

Comment: Thanks for that github project, after tinkering I've found out that it does not like my data binding `Content="{Binding Path=SecurityAuditOverallResult}"`  I'm using to connect to my model and change the label dynamically. If I change the label content to a static string like Content="Failed" just like your first two examples, it works exactly like  it does in your example. Any ideas on what could be causing this? I have checked if my binding is producing an actual value of "failed", but if I use my binded content it always returns null when it triggers the converter method.

Comment: I found a solution that does the trick in the meantime. See edit.

Comment: The same solution must work for Label as well as for Textbox. I think your problem was just that you didn't set the UpdateSourceTrigger value to PropertyChanged, or you are not binding to a dependency property, and it's either not updating your initial null value or your binding is not working. I'll update the repo to show a possible way with mvvm

Comment: I have updated the repo. Click the button to set the label content. The background color changes as expected.